# Cordova ajax POST net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am getting net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED in remote device console. The ajax image upload works file in desktop browser but not working after build.

Please below check image.

[image: Please check image]

Comment: use a proper webserver to server your page over `http://`. Ajax over the `file:///` protocol is not allowed.

Comment: What should I do to allow it. Its a input type="file".
I user following header to allow request: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: Nothing to do with input type="file". Read what I wrote about the protocol you're using to view the page. If you just double-click the file in your explorer and display it in the browser, you can't use ajax with it at all (due to security). You have to test using an actual webserver, even if it's just one on your local machine. The address in the browser bar must start with `http://` or `https://`, but not `file:///`

Comment: No its not direct file url. Its html's input type file which works on desktop browser but not in app. I am using FormData() object for ajax.

Comment: Its work on mobile when not image selected and it successfully send FormData to server.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what I am saying. In the screenshot above it's very clear that you're accessing the page as `file:///android_asset/www/index.html`. It's right there in the address bar. If you then send an ajax request from there, it won't work, because you have to use `http://` for the page you're sending from (and also for the URL you're requesting). Like I said nothing to do with "input file type" - that's a detail of the HTML markup, not the way the page is actually loaded into the browser.

Comment: Yes I got your point. Do you have any idea on how to submit form+file with cordova/webview? Other solution?

Comment: Yes. Use an actual webserver to load your page, like I suggested. Is that really so hard to understand?? Once you do that, then test it again and presumably it should work (since you said it worked in another environment). Beyond that I can't comment on whether what you've done is correct because there's no code listed here.

Comment: In cordova normal ajax post working with orgin file:///. I will try with iframe from live server. Thank you for the help.

Comment: That may be some specific thing to do with the cordova test environment but it won't work in a standard browser environment

Comment: You right. It will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

I use above cordova plugin to upload the file. The ajax file upload will not work even with cordova whitelist plugin.